# Float two divs left and one right

Tags: html, css

My code structure looks like this

```html
<div style="height: 100px;
            Width: 200px;"> <!-- Container -->
  <div style="float: left;
              height: 50px;
              Width: 100px;
              background-color: red;">
  </div>
  <div style="float: left;
              height: 50px;
              Width: 100px;
              background-color: blue;">
  </div>
  <div style="float: right;
              height: 50px;
              Width: 100px;
              background-color: green;">
  </div>
</div>
```

But the right position of elements should look like this:

```
┌──────┬──────┐
│ red  │green │
├──────┼──────┘
│ blue │
└──────┘
```

I cannot change or add any additional code, the only way is with CSS. 
How should I float the divs to be in the right order as I mentioned above?

Edit: My code doesn't and can't contain div with clear.

Answer (score 1):

you dont need floating for that. disable all floating using `!important` to override the inline styles, and then use `:nth-of-type()` to select the green div and position it absolutely with right and top equal 0;

```css
div {
  position: relative;
}
div > div{
  float: none !important;
}
div > div:nth-of-type(3) {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top:0;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 100px; Width: 200px;">
  <!-- Container -->
  <div style="float:left; height: 50px; Width:100px; background-color:red;">
  </div>
  <div style="float:left; height: 50px; Width:100px; background-color:blue;">
  </div>
  <div style="float:right; height: 50px; Width:100px; background-color:green;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My html code doesn't contain div styling with clear.

Comment: @Navitua makes no difference. simply adjust the `nth-of-type()` accordingly. i have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use clear: left on the blue box to push it down and then use negative margin on the green box to push it up.

```html
<div style="height: 100px; Width: 200px;">
  <!-- Container -->

  <div style="float:left;height: 50px; 
                    width:100px; background-color:red;">
  </div>
  <div style="float:left;clear:left;
                    height: 50px; Width:100px; background-color:blue;">
  </div>
  <div style="float:left; height:50px; 
                    width:100px; background-color:green;margin-top:-50px;">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: My html code doesn't contain div styling with clear.

Comment: It is not needed. I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is more like a puzzle instead of a legit question but here goes.

With the proper use of margins and positions in addition to assigning null to clear property one can accomplish your scenario.

```html
 <div style="height: 100px; Width: 200px;">
<!-- Container -->
<div style="float:left; height: 50px; Width:100px; background-color:red;"></div>
<div style="float: right; height: 50px; margin-top: 50px;Width:100px; background-color:blue;position: absolute;"></div>
<div style="clear: none;"></div>
<div style=" height: 50px; margin-left: 100px;margin-bottom: 50px;Width:100px; background-color:green;"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the same HTML structure, you could select the `div`s in CSS using `:nth-child(N)`. In this case you'd just need to update the blue (2) and green (4) boxes, and the one with the `clear:both` style (3):

```css
div > div:nth-child(2) {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
div > div:nth-child(3) {
    display: none;
}
div > div:nth-child(4) {
    margin-top: -100px;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 100px; Width: 200px;">
  <!-- Container -->
  <div style="float:left; height: 50px; Width:100px; background-color:red;">
  </div>
  <div style="float:left; height: 50px; Width:100px; background-color:blue;">
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  <div style="float:right; height: 50px; Width:100px; background-color:green;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Notice that this will work for this particular example. It would be ideal if the container `div` had an id and use that instead of `div >`.

---

For a more generic solution that would work independently of the height of the boxes, you could use `transform:translate()` like this:

```
div > div:nth-child(2) {
    transform:translate(0%, 100%);
}
div > div:nth-child(3) {
    display:none;
}
div > div:nth-child(4) {
    transform:translate(0%, -100%);
}
```

As you can see on this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eekhjv3n/1/