# Need to align a button under an image with a text at their right

Tags: css, alignment, css-position

¡Hello! I've looking for some questions like this, but i only found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29830205/float-two-divs-left-and-one-right), and its solution is useless for me.

I have a website where some books are shown, it is edicionesparalelo.com, and another one where people can buy those books: tienda.edicionesparalelo.com I'd want to put a button under each book image which says "Ir a la tienda" (Go to the store), but i don't know how can i align the button under the image and keep the text like it is now. I've tried floating and positioning but no way.

An example of the book pages [in this link](http://edicionesparalelo.com/tu-y-yo-y-las-primeras-lluvias/). What i want is to put a button under the image.

I strangely feel that this will be duplicated, but i sware i searched the web for a whole hour.

Could you help me? Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you place a button in there, and people can help you position it with some CSS. Perhaps wrap the image in a div and place the button in that div under the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way of creating the layout that you need.  Create two block level elements, one to hold the image and the button and the other to hold the content (header and text).

Float the `.thumb-panel` to the left and keep the `.text-panel` as a regular inflow element.

Adjust margins, borders and padding as needed.

```css
.content-panel{
  overflow: auto; /* keep the float contained within this panel */
  border: 1px dotted blue;
}
.thumb-panel {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 20px; /* for example */
}
.thumb-panel img {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 20px; /* for example */
}
.thumb-panel button{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.text-panel {
  overflow: auto; /* prevents text flow wrapping around floated panel */
  border: 1px solid gray;

}
```

```html
<div class="content-panel">
  <div class="thumb-panel">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/80x120">
    <button>Button</button>
  </div>
  <div class="text-panel">
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer facilisis velit ut neque tempor quis cursus tortor suscipit. Curabitur rutrum magna vitae arcu pharetra eget cursus ante accumsan. Nunc commodo malesuada adipiscing. Pellentesque consequat laoreet sagittis. Sed sit amet erat augue. Morbi consectetur, elit quis iaculis cursus, mauris nulla hendrerit augue, ut faucibus elit sapien vitae justo. In a ipsum malesuada nulla rutrum luctus. Donec a enim sapien. Sed ultrices ligula ac neque vulputate luctus. Suspendisse pretium pretium felis, in aliquet risus fringilla at. Nunc cursus sagittis commodo.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```